# storing output of history command in a text file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, history, ksh

My script code is

```
history > a.txt
```

but this does not store anything in the text file. However when I use the command in prompt it works.

I am working with a KornShell (ksh) script on UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

'history' command is disabled outside the command line (like your script). You can enable it using:

`set -o history`

Now the command 'history' will be available to your script.

Comment: It works for me. Did you run "set -o history" and it was successful?